# Email of membership receipt needs specific custom tokens added - how to find them?

Tags: civimember, tokens

I am trying to work with an existing CiviCRM setup I have stepped into.

The automatic email of a donation or membership payment needs more features added.

1) The Company number 
2) the type of product being purchased (as in Silver membership, Gold, Student or Retired), 
3) the official registration of the body they have donated to or paid membership to, and 
4) the type of donation that may be given, as in for campaign A or for campaign B.

My organization is using CiviMail, CiviContributes and CiviMember.  We do not use CiviEvent even though it is installed.

I do not know where to find, in this slightly customized version of CiviCRM, 4.1.3, those fields or those tokens. Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

There are about 1300 members/supporters being managed with this system since 2011.  I think there are a lot of legacy aspects that have been tried and left hanging, looking as though they can do thing, but they don't, like CiviEvent.

Thanks in advance for your help.

------------- existing message template ----------------

{capture assign=headerStyle}colspan="2" style="text-align: left; padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; background-color: #eee;"{/capture}
{capture assign=labelStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; background-color: #f7f7f7;"{/capture}
{capture assign=valueStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999;"{/capture}

{if $formValues.receipt_text_signup}

{$formValues.receipt_text_signup|htmlize}

{elseif $formValues.receipt_text_renewal}

{$formValues.receipt_text_renewal|htmlize}

{else}

{ts}Thanks for your support.{/ts}

{/if}
    {if ! $cancelled}

{ts}Please print this receipt for your records.{/ts}

{ts}SPECIAL Association for PUBLIC GOOD (Australia){/ts}

{ts}ABN 15 555 555 555{/ts}

{/if}
   
  
  
   
    
     {if !$lineItem}
     
      
       {ts}Membership Information{/ts}
      
     
     
      
       {ts}Membership Type{/ts}
      
      
       {$membership_name}
      
     
     {/if}
     {if ! $cancelled}
     {if !$lineItem}
      
       
        {ts}Membership Start Date{/ts}
       
       
        {$mem_start_date}
       
      
      
       
        {ts}Membership End Date{/ts}
       
       
        {$mem_end_date}
       
      
      {/if}
      {if $formValues.total_amount}
       
        
         {ts}Membership Fee{/ts}
        
       
       {if $formValues.contributionType_name}
        
         
          {ts}Contribution Type{/ts}
         
         
          {$formValues.contributionType_name}
         
        
       {/if}

```
   {if $lineItem}
   {foreach from=$lineItem item=value key=priceset}
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" {$valueStyle}>
       <table> {* FIXME: style this table so that it looks like the text version (justification, etc.) *}
        <tr>
         <th>{ts}Item{/ts}</th>
         <th>{ts}Fee{/ts}</th>
     <th>{ts}Membership Start Date{/ts}</th>
     <th>{ts}Membership End Date{/ts}</th>
        </tr>
        {foreach from=$value item=line}
         <tr>
          <td>
      {if $line.html_type eq 'Text'}{$line.label}{else}{$line.field_title} - {$line.label}{/if} {if $line.description}<div>{$line.description|truncate:30:"..."}</div>{/if} 
          </td>
          <td>
           {$line.line_total|crmMoney}
          </td>
          <td>
           {$line.start_date}
          </td>
      <td>
           {$line.end_date}
          </td>
         </tr>
        {/foreach}
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
   {/foreach}
  {/if}
   <tr>
    <td {$labelStyle}>
     {ts}Amount{/ts}
    </td>
    <td {$valueStyle}>
     {$formValues.total_amount|crmMoney}
    </td>
   </tr>
   {if $receive_date}
    <tr>
     <td {$labelStyle}>
      {ts}Received Date{/ts}
     </td>
     <td {$valueStyle}>
      {$receive_date|truncate:10:''|crmDate}
     </td>
    </tr>
   {/if}
   {if $formValues.paidBy}
    <tr>
     <td {$labelStyle}>
      {ts}Paid By{/ts}
     </td>
     <td {$valueStyle}>
      {$formValues.paidBy}
     </td>
    </tr>
    {if $formValues.check_number}
     <tr>
      <td {$labelStyle}>
       {ts}Check Number{/ts}
      </td>
      <td {$valueStyle}>
       {$formValues.check_number}
      </td>
     </tr>
    {/if}
   {/if}
  {/if}
 {/if}
</table>
```

{if $isPrimary}

```
  {if $contributeMode ne 'notify' and !$isAmountzero and !$is_pay_later }
   <tr>
    <th {$headerStyle}>
     {ts}Billing Name and Address{/ts}
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td {$labelStyle}>
     {$billingName}<br />
     {$address}
    </td>
   </tr>
  {/if}

  {if $contributeMode eq 'direct' and !$isAmountzero and !$is_pay_later}
   <tr>
    <th {$headerStyle}>
     {ts}Credit Card Information{/ts}
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td {$valueStyle}>
     {$credit_card_type}<br />
     {$credit_card_number}
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td {$labelStyle}>
     {ts}Expires{/ts}
    </td>
    <td {$valueStyle}>
     {$credit_card_exp_date|truncate:7:''|crmDate}
    </td>
   </tr>
  {/if}

 </table>
</td>
```

{/if}

{if $customValues}
   
    
     
      
       
        {ts}Membership Options{/ts}
       
      
      {foreach from=$customValues item=value key=customName}
       
        
         {$customName}
        
        
         {$value}
        
       
      {/foreach}
     
    
   
  {/if}

Comment: Hi Thomas - welcome - if you are asking where to find the templates, go to Admin. > Communications > Message Templates then System Templates Message (tab) or /civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1

Comment: If you have the funds it may save a lot of headache to get an expert to show you around the system that has been left in your care. If that is not an option then we currently have capacity to provide some free mentoring for you if you want to get in touch via our site - fuzion.co.nz

Comment: If you are on 4.1.3, make it a priority to get upgraded.  There are numerous bug fixes, security fixes and enhancements since 4.1.3 - but you will want to understand your local customisations first so you can assess whether those are still needed and how they can be updated.

Comment: Thanks +peternz and +Aidan - I am asking for support/advice to do both options from management.  My feeling is that this CiviCRM is broken and we cannot get what we need - which is to have CiviContribution issue a receipt using information from CiviMembership.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to the CiviCRM SE page!

With respect to the membership type/product, those should be delineated in any membership receipt template without any additional customization needed.  And since you're working with Civi 4.1.3, if these are memberships on  behalf of an organization, the receipt should include the company name.  (This behavior doesn't work correctly in 5.x, unfortunately.)  If the company number is a custom field, you should be able to pull it in based on its ID number, located at the end of its editing link.  For example, ../civicrm/admin/custom/group/field/update?action=update&reset=1&gid=5&id=11 would be referenced as {contact.custom_11} as a token.

In the contribution template, the type of donation should already be included - is it not coming through, in your testing?

With respect to the official registration details, how are those currently stored in Civi?

Comment: Hi @Lesley Carter - BackOffice

the full details of the membership type/product does not come through with the membership receipt. Its says "membership dues" and it needs to have a second field showing the type of dues - Gold / Silver / Bronze / plus Student. 

I need to find out how to find a field code for the type of membership due being made.

The editing link - that information is very helpful. Is this an editing link?  
https://contacts.mynonprofitgenericwebsite.org.au/civicrm/member/add?reset=1&action=add&context=standalone

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how the membership looks in Civi (not in the receipt)?  That would help us help you a bit better as it's difficult to say without knowing how you've set up your membership structure.